# Backpropagation example

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist

I'm trying to implement my own neural network, but I'm not very confident that my math is correct.

I'm doing the MNIST digit recognition, so I have a softmaxed output of 10 probabilities. as output. I then compute my delta output thus:

```
delta_output = vector of outputs - one-hot encoded actual label
```

delta_output is a matrix of dimension 10 x 1.

Then I compute the delta for the weights of the last hidden layer thus:

```
delta_hidden = weight_hidden.transpose * delta_output * der_hidden_activation(output_hidden)
```

Assuming there are N nodes in the last hidden layer, weight_hidden is a matrix of dimension of N by 10, delta_output from above is 10x1, and the result of der_hidden_activation(output_hidden) is  N x 1.

Now, my first question here is, should the multiplication of delta_output and der_hidden_activation(output_hidden) return a 10 x N matrix using outer product? I think the I need to do a Hadamard product of this resulting matrix with the untouched weights to get delta_hidden to be N x 10 still.

Finally I multiply this delta_hidden by my learning rate and subtract it from the original weight of the last hidden layer to get my new weights.

My second and final question here is, did I miss anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming there are N nodes in the last hidden layer, weight_hidden is a matrix of dimension of N by 10, delta_output from above is 10x1, and the result of der_hidden_activation(output_hidden) is N x 1.

When going from a layer of N neurons (hidden layer), to a layer of M neurons (output layer), under [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), the weight matrix dimensions should be M x N. So for the back propagation stage, going from layer of M neurons (output), to a layer of N neurons (hidden layer), use the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of the weight matrix which will give you a matrix of dimension (N x M).

> Now, my first question here is, should the multiplication of delta_output and der_hidden_activation(output_hidden) return a 10 x N matrix using outer product? 
>   I think the I need to do a Hadamard product of this resulting matrix with the untouched weights to get delta_hidden to be N x 10 still.

Yes you need to use [hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), however you can't multiply delta_output and der_hidden_activation(output_hidden) since these are matrices of different dimensions (10 x 1, and N x 1 respectively). Instead you multiply the transpose of the hidden_weight matrix (N x 10) by delta_output (10 x 1) to get a matrix of N x 1, and then perform the hadamard product with der_hidden_activation(output_hidden).

If I am translating this correctly...

hidden_weight matrix =
[image]

delta_output = 
[image]

delta_hidden = 
[image]

der_hidden_activation(output_hidden) = 
[image]

Plugging this into the BP formula...

[image]

As you can see, you need to multiply the transpose of the weight_hidden (N x 10) with delta_output (10 x 1) first to produce a matrix (N x 1), and then you use hadamard product with der_hidden_activation(output_hidden).

> Finally I multiply this delta_hidden by my learning rate and subtract it from the original weight of the last hidden layer to get my new weights.

You don't multiply delta_hidden by the learning rate. You need to use the learning rate on a bias and delta weight matrix...

The delta weight matrix is a matrix of the same dimensions as your (hidden) weight matrix and is calculated using the formula...

[image]

And then you can easily apply the learning rate...

[image]

[Incidentally, I just answered a similar question on AISE which might help shed some light and goes into more detail about the matricies to use during backpropagation.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/20053/how-to-perform-back-propagation-with-different-sized-layers/20108#20108)